# How to view debug code in Thin console window?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel, thin

In Mongrel, we are able to see any ruby debug code. After installing thin and doing `thin start`. I don't see any debug code on the console window.

Is this nromal?

Are we supposed to use `tail -f log/development.log` in a new console window to view the debug code?

Comment: Yes. The solution with tail is normal, and you should use it.

Comment: Provide your comment as an answer so I can consider it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The solution with tail is normal, and you should use it.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try to start your server this way :

```
rails server thin
```

It shows your log, in Rails 3 at least.

Comment: Thx but how can i start thin in this way with ssl options ? this is my cmd: thin start -p 3000 --ssl --ssl-key-file .ssl/localhost.key --ssl-cert-file .ssl/localhost.crt

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Procfile](http://neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend/) with [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman):

Procfile

```
web: thin start -p $PORT
logger: tail -f log/development.log
```

Example

```
$ foreman start -p 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a small code snippet in your `config.ru` file, and thin output all app logs to the console. You do not need to `tail` the log file, and it keeps log coloring intact

Details here: [Thin server: ouput rails application logs to console, as 'rails s' does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158675)