# How to show application requests on terminal window while using Thin and Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, thin, rails-3-upgrade

I started using Thin instead of WEBrick in development (Rails version 3.0.9)

With WEBbrick, I would see all the requests listed (and calls to the database) in the terminal window while the server was running.

How do I get that with thin? When I do `thin start` the only output I see is:

```
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: `tail -f log/development.log` FTW!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view debug code in Thin console window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908771/how-to-view-debug-code-in-thin-console-window)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `thin start -V`.
https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/runner.rb#L134

```
opts.on_tail("-V", "--trace", "Set tracing on (log raw request/response)")
```

Comment: this works, but I've been getting some really weird output, it looks like images or something like that...

Comment: This isn't the correct solution - these are HTTP request headers, and there is no Rails routing, rendering or SQL logging

Answer (score -1):

try `rails server thin -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development`

or run it with bundle

```
bundle exec rails server thin -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
```